# Is there any way to print the expressions of sympy pretty in pydroid3

Tags: python, tkinter, terminal, printing, sympy

Two questions, the first question, is it possible to print expressions of sympy In an attractive way in the terminal of pydroid3 `Especially in pydroid3 terminal because most of the ways like below has no effect at all`.

```
init_printing(use_unicode=True)
```

The second question, in tkinter ui system `or in tkinter ui in general`, how to display those expressions as Label or anything similar, if not possible is there any other GUI library This is possible in it.

```
import sympy as sy

x, y, z = sy.symbols("x y z")

sy.init_printing(use_unicode=True) # not working

print(x*sy.sqrt(y))

print(z*sy.cos(x))

print(sy.Matrix([[1, 2], [3, 5], [x,y]]))
```

`I really hope I asked correctly`.

Comment: Should  be `sy.init_printing()` instead of `sy.init_printing(use_unicode=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SymPy's `ppprint` to print as a pretty string or`pretty` to get the string:

```
In [2]: e = sqrt(x*y**2)

In [3]: pprint(e)
   ______
  ╱    2 
╲╱  x⋅y  

In [4]: s = pretty(e)

In [5]: s
Out[5]: '   ______\n  ╱    2 \n╲╱  x⋅y  '

In [6]: print(s)
   ______
  ╱    2 
╲╱  x⋅y
```